# Can a neuron output a value other than 1 or 0

Tags: neural-networks

I need to know whether a neuron output can take any value other than a binary value.
 i.e

```
0 or 1 

1 or -1
```

except values like these can a neuron output any other value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output depends on the type of neuron you employ - be it sigmoid, tahn, rectified linear, binary etc. To specifically answer your question, the output does not have to be binary.

For example, $\text{ReLU}(x) = \max(0,x)$ which is clearly unbounded above.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the output of a neuron in an Artificial Neural Network is a sigmoid function of the inputs weighted by the parameters of the neuron.

So it takes other values than 0 or 1 - it takes values BETWEEN 0 and 1. But, as you can see from the sigmoid function (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function), depending on the parameters of the neuron its output will easily fall very close to 0 or 1, as these values are the asymptotical values of the sigmoid.

Comment: but the output of a neuron can be "excited" or "not excited" so what does a real value in middle mean

Comment: "excited" and "not excited" are biological interpretations in an Artificial Neuron, and one usually consider that the neuron is excited if the output is bigger than 0.5 . You can use the raw output if you want, instead of transforming it to binary.